# Skip rows which has a specified value

Tags: php, pdo

My requirement is to get the count of rows. In my MySQL I have a column (item) which has the value as "1265855". When I get the count I need to ignore rows which has `1265855` in column `item`. How can I do this in a sql statement?

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM stock WHERE availability = :availability  AND item = :item";
$stement = $con->prepare($sql);
$stement->execute(array(':availability'=> $val1, ':item' => $val2)); // ignore 1265855
$result = $stement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Adding `AND item <> 1265855` to the query would work.

Comment: By the way, change fetchAll to [fetchColumn()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn)

Comment: @Sougata Thank you. ` AND item = :item AND item <> :ignoreVal`:  and then  `$stement->execute(array(':availability'=> $val1, ':item' => $val2, ':ignoreVal=> "1265855"));` Will work? Can you please explain briefly what `<>` means?

Comment: It means *either less than* or *greater than* the specified value; which means *not equal to*

Comment: @HankyPanky Thanks. What if it's a string instead of a int?

Comment: Then it will loosely mean *not same*

Comment: Why we just don't use `!=`? It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not trying to also filter on the item, this should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
          FROM stock 
         WHERE availability = :availability  
           AND item != :item";

$stement = $con->prepare($sql);
$params = array(':availability'=> $val1, ':item' => '1265855'); 
$stement->execute($params); // ignore 1265855
$result = $stement->fetchAll();
```

Not sure what you are doing with `$val2` otherwise tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **<>** to your query.

**<>** is called Not Equal To and this can also be used when you are excluding a row in your query. Note that in some versions of SQL this operator may be written as **!=**

Here's how to apply it in your current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM stock WHERE availability = :availability AND item <> 1265855";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM stock WHERE availability = :availability AND item != 1265855";
```

for string:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM stock WHERE availability = :availability AND item != 'string'";
```